# Grails 3 how to access favicon, icon and tile files from app root

Tags: grails

I have an Grails app that runs on http://localhost:8092

Different browsers look for certain files in the root path (http://localhost:8092/), for instance: favicon.ico, browserconfig.xml (looks for ms tiles on Windows), site.webmanifest (looks for icons + app name on Android that is used when adding the web app to home screen), safari-pinned-tab.svg (for Safari), favicon-32x32.png/favicon-16x16.png (for alternative size favicons), etc.

What I can make work is favicon.ico, adding it to grails-app/assets/images and using the asset pipeline in the GSP:

But the rest doesn't work. Also site.webmanifest and browserconfig.xml files have paths to certain images to be used as Android icons or Windows tiles respectively. I can change those paths to be under /assets/... but those files should be available under the Grails app root.

Looked in the docs and tried to find examples online but couldn't find anything for Grails 3.

How can I configure Grails to allow those files to be accessed from the app's root path?

BTW I'm using Grails 3.2.9

Answer (score 1):

Basing on [the release notes](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/releases/tag/v3.0.12):

> In order to resolve an issue around how POST requests are treated for
>   REST applications on non-existent resources, static resources located
>   in src/main/resources/public are now resolved under the /static/** URI
>   by default, instead of the base URI /**. If you wish to restore the
>   previous behaviour add the following configuration:
>
> ```
> grails.resources.pattern = '/**'
> ```

It's also resolving issue (even for rest-api profile app) with:

> WARN org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/favicon.ico] in DispatcherServlet with name 'grailsDispatcherServlet'

Answer (score 0):

Put all of them in src/main/resources/public

https://gsp.grails.org/latest/guide/resources.html

Comment: Created a file in /src/main/resources/public/browserconfig.xml then on http://localhost:8092/browserconfig.xml I get Error: Page Not Found (404) Path: /browserconfig.xml. I believe the file is served from /static not from /